# CsvHelper: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, csvhelper

My map class is

```
 public sealed class ProductMap : CsvClassMap<Product>
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.VatRate).ConvertUsing(row =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetField<string>("VatRate"))) throw new Exception("VatRate is required.");
                return row.GetField<string>("VatRate");
            }).Index(0);
        }
    }
```

My Product Class is

```
public class Product
{
    public decimal VatRate { get; set; }
}
```

While trying to get the records in a list,

```
IEnumerable<Product> products  = csv.GetRecords<Product>().ToList();
```

i get the following error.

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is the StackTrace

> at BackFinal.Parse.<.ctor>b__1(Exception ex, ICsvReader row) in
>   d:\Projects\BackFinal\CSVImport.cs:line 80    at
>   CsvHelper.CsvReader.d__63`1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Projects\CsvHelper\src\CsvHelper\CsvReader.cs:line 944    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   BackFinal.Parse..ctor(UploadFilesResult R) in
>   d:\Projects\BackFinal\CSVImport.cs:line 87

if i change the type of the `VatRate` in `Product` class from `decimal` to `string`, i do not get any errors.

Can i have a solution please?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? Perhaps it has something to do with a separator used to separate digits in decimal and to separate individual items in CSV lines.

Comment: In ProductMap were the <decimal> or <string> before you made the to VatRate?